# Converting YAML file to Groovy map results with snakeyaml returns in undesirable format

Tags: groovy, snakeyaml

I'm attempting to parse a YAML file using snakeyaml in Groovy. The goal is to create a map that I can ultimately search from.

The file I'm using is structured like:

```
maintainers:
  - component: PowerPuff Girls
    pg: Utonium Labs
    people:
      - Buttercup
      - Blossom
      - Bubbles
    files:
      - sugar/*
      - spice/*
      - things/*nice*
      - chemicalx/*
  - component: Gangreen Gang
    pg: Villians
    people:
      - Ace
      - Snake
      - Big Billy
    files:
      - ace/*
      - snake/*
```

The problem is: When I create a map and return the value, the `maintainers` value is throwing off the format from what I would hope for. Additionally, it seems like none of the String values are converted to a String. The output is:

```
[maintainers:[[component:PowerPuff Girls, pg:Utonium Labs, people:[Buttercup, Blossom, Bubbles], files:[sugar/*, spice/*, things/*nice*, chemicalx/*]], [component:Gangreen Gang, pg:Villians, people:[Ace, Snake, Big Billy], files:[ace/*, snake/*]]]]
```

In a perfect world, I would have:

```
[component: 'PowerPuff Girls', pg: 'Utonium Labs', people: ['Buttercup', 'Blossom', 'Bubbles'], files: ['sugar/*','spice/*','things/*nice*', 'chemicalx']], 
[component: 'Gangreen Gang', pg: 'Villians', people: ['Ace', 'Snake', 'Big Billy'], files: ['ace/*','snake/*']]
```

I must be missing something silly with reformatting this map. I welcome all suggestions!

Step 1: Loading the file as Map

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml()
Map yamlMap = yaml.load(yamlFile)
```

Step 2: Returning map to observe format
return yamlMap

Results in:

```
[maintainers:[[component:PowerPuff Girls, pg:Utonium Labs, people:[Buttercup, Blossom, Bubbles], files:[sugar/*, spice/*, things/*nice*, chemicalx/*]], [component:Gangreen Gang, pg:Villians, people:[Ace, Snake, Big Billy], files:[ace/*, snake/*]]]]
```

I attempted to define individual keys and values separately and reconstruct them, but it wasn't pulling the groupings as expected. E.g: `def myVariable = yamlMap['maintainers']['component']`

Comment: `yamlMap['maintainers'][0]['component']` should return `PowerPuff Girls`

Comment: the same but dot notation `yamlMap.maintainers[0].component`

Comment: probably the nearest to your `ideal world` format is json.

`yamlMap.maintainers.each{i-> println groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(i)  }`

Comment: Thanks everyone. That helps clean it up a bit, but one question I still have is getting the values as Strings.

For example, if I were to use `yamlMap.containsValue('PowerPuff Girls')` it fails since it is not a String in the map conversion. 

With that said, since we're using a position or integer in the examples, would it just make more sense to use `indexOf()` instead of searching for strings and finding position?

Comment: I have a hard time following, what you are after. Maintainers holds a list of maps and this is what you get. Are you struggling with the data structure?  You could change your YAML then.   Or are you battling `.toString()` from Groovy?  You should never ever use it as an serialization format.  Stick with YAML or JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the nearest to your `ideal world` format is json.

```
yamlMap.maintainers.each{ i-> println groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(i) }
```

if you want to search for item(s) where `component` matches some value:

```
println yamlMap.maintainers.find{i-> i.component=='Gangreen Gang' } // equals
println yamlMap.maintainers.find{i-> i.component=~'green' }         // regex match
println yamlMap.maintainers.findAll{i-> i.component=~'green' }      // find all
println yamlMap.maintainers.findIndexOf{i-> i.component=~'green' }  // return index instead of element
```

more groovy methods on list/collection:

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html

Comment: The search part is exactly what I was missing. Thank you for the examples and resource.